# Change background in custom blogger template that hasn't body.backround

Tags: html, css, templates, background, blogger

I have custom Galauness template on blogger (http://nethoroskop.blogspot.com) but I would like to upload my own image...Can you tell me how? In html code there is NOT

```
body{ background
```

There a lot of other `background`s (like `post background`,`total-wrapper background`, `lightbox-container-image-data-box` `background`,etc) but not `body.background` at all!

Answer (score 3):

You need to find and edit this section to add your own background image:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y417/trynitezoo/winterpaper_zps5a2f39a3.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

or you can override the background image. You only need to copy and paste the following code in the header tag section and replace the YOUR NEW IMAGE PATH to the image url you needed:

```
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url('http://YOUR NEW IMAGE PATH') !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background of the body to an image this would be the best way. Change the `<body>` to this:

```
<body background="image.jpg">
```

Tutorial from : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp